# Xcode - How do I delete a branch with blank in name - the given reference name ist not valid

Tags: xcode, git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I'm having trouble with Git. I hope someone can give me a helpful hint.

After I tried to get the status of the remote branch via source control in Xcode using 'fetch and refresh' to update the remote branch, the following error message appeared. But the branch 'Climeaid 2' never existed before.

[image: First error after fetch and refresh]

Among my branches there was suddenly a branch with the same name as my checked out branch, but now with a blank and (2) in the name. Unfortunately I cannot delete the branch:

[image: delete error branch with blank]

Now I can't do anything about Source Control either. When I press push, pull or commit the same error message from my first screenshot always appears.

what can I do now? How can I delete the branch with the space in name?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Xcode git capabilities have always been dodgy. I’d quit Xcode and either use the `git` command line or a [Git client](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).